# kendo k-calendar weekend text color

Tags: css, kendo-ui

Could anybody please tell me, how would I simply make the weekend numbers in this date picker red?  Here is what I have so far in css:

```
.k-calendar .k-weekend
{ 
  background: red;
}
```

This is what it produces,

[image]

But instead I want to have something like this:

[image]

Please disregard the difference in formatting.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use something like this

```
.k-calendar .k-weekend .k-link
{ 
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was looking to apply a property to text, but that didn't work, so what I needed was the k-link. :)